# I want to check if a table is populated or not then I ran the appropriate select statement.

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How do I write this in SQL code:

**If TABLEF and TABLEG is not populated  run this query:**

```
SELECT
  A.BEG_DT_TM,
  A.END_DT_TM,
  D.BEG_DT_TM,
  D.END_DT_TM
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLED D
  ON D.A_EXEC_ID = A.A_EXEC_ID
WHERE A.PERSON_ID = ?
  AND A.BEG_DT_TM >= ?
  AND A.BEG_DT_TM <= ?
```

**If TABLEF and TABLEG is populated  run this query:**

```
SELECT 
  A.BEG_DT_TM,  
  A.END_DT_TM,
  D.BEG_DT_TM,
  D.END_DT_TM,
  G.C_ID
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLED D
  ON D.A_EXEC_ID = A.A_EXEC_ID
INNER JOIN TABLEF F
  ON F.A_RECYC_ID = A.A_RECYC_ID
INNER JOIN TABLEG G
  ON G.BL_APP_ID = F.BL_APP_ID
WHERE A.RCD IN (?)
  AND A.BEG_DT_TM >= ?
  AND A.BEG_DT_TM <= ?
  AND D.BEG_DT_TM <= ?
  AND D.END_DT_TM > ?
  AND (1 = ?
       OR G.C_ID = ?)
```

I want to check if a table is populated or not then I ran the appropriate select statement. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify one point: there are no filtering criteria on TABLEF and TABLEG beyond checking whether they are populated?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a `left join`:

```
SELECT A.BEG_DT_TM, A.END_DT_TM, D.BEG_DT_TM, D.END_DT_TM, G.C_ID
FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN
     TABLED D
     ON D.A_EXEC_ID = A.A_EXEC_ID LEFT JOIN
     TABLEF F
     ON F.A_RECYC_ID = A.A_RECYC_ID LEFT JOIN
     TABLEG G
     ON G.BL_APP_ID = F.BL_APP_ID AND
        (1 = ? OR G.C_ID = ?)
WHERE A.RCD IN (?) AND
      A.BEG_DT_TM >= ? AND
      A.BEG_DT_TM <= ? AND
      D.BEG_DT_TM <= ? AND
      D.END_DT_TM > ?;
```

This is not 100% the same as the logic in your question.  This query always returns 5 columns and not 4.  "Not populated" is taken to mean "no match on the conditions".  And there might be other subtle differences.  However, I suspect that this is likely to do what you want.

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff, what is the impact on performance if I do it using left join? Is it not cleaner and more efficient if I just split my query into two separate select statements?

Comment: also what if TABLEF and TABLEG don't exist in some domain but it exist in other domain. will the left join break the query?

Comment: @MTech . . . As I say, this does not do exactly what your question describes.  It is close and it seems like it reasonably might do what you intend.  As for the performance of `left join`, it would be negligible on an empty table.